# How does the Polymorph spell affect procreation?

Tags: spells, dnd-3.5e, polymorph

The Polymorph spell alters the body of one willing target, changing it into a different creature- Potentially from a different type.

If someone were to breed whilst under the effect of this spell, what would the result be? Would the child be born as if the polymorphed parent were truly a member of the race they turned into? Or as if they had always been their original race?

Considering that there is no way that I know of to let a single casting of polymorph last long enough to carry a pregnancy to full term: What are the effects of a woman being imregnated whilst polymorphed, or polymorphed whilst pregnant?

Comment: You might be interested in answers to [this question.](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/51657/8610) Also, has this issue shown up at the gaming table, or is this idle curiosity?

Comment: A bit of both and neither I suppose. I am worldbuilding for a new campaign, and trying to figure out the specifics behind a family descended from one polymorphed Dragon pretending to be something else.

Comment: Then it kind of sounds like you've an answer. `:-)`

Comment: "Potentially from a different type"? What would change your creature type in 3.5's polymorph?

Comment: You may take any form you wish from a list of types, + your own type if not already on that list.

Comment: A similar Pathfinder question: [What happens when one conceives a child while polymorphed into another species?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/136543/33569)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## The DM decides if it's possible to procreate while affected by [*polymorph*](http://dndsrd.net/spellsPtoR.html#polymorph)

This isn't explicitly covered by the official rules. It remains unmentioned by, for example, Skip Williams's four Rules of the Game Web columns on "[Polymorphing Revisited](http://archive.wizards.com/default.asp?x=dnd/rg/20060502a)." Hence the only thing the reader *does* have to work with officially is just one phrase.

The 4th-level Sor/Wiz spell [*polymorph*](http://dndsrd.net/spellsPtoR.html#polymorph) [trans] (*Player's Handbook* 263) says that it's like the 2nd-level Sor/Wiz spell [*alter self*](http://dndsrd.net/spellsAtoB.html#alter-self) [trans] (*PH* 197) except where noted, and one way that's *not* noted is that the spell *alter self* says the following: "Any part of the body… that is separated from the whole reverts to its true form." By extension, then, this applies equally to the spell *polymorph*.

Thus, with that in mind, the DM must rule—at some point during procreation—what the *alter self* spell's description means *exactly* when the spell *alter self* says (and, by extension, the spell *polymorph* inherits) that "part of the body… that is separated from the whole reverts to its true form."

This reader can offer two options, and given its vagueness, other options are likely:

- If the DM rules that during procreation the creature loses part of its body, then—unless the creatures are mundanely compatible—, no offspring will result.
- If the DM rules that during procreation the creature doesn't lose part of its body, then—even if the creatures aren't normally mundanely compatible—, offspring may result.

While I'm certain some 3rd-party supplements delve into this area more deeply, the official rules would see the DM decide if a creature that's affected by a *polymorph* spell can procreate with a creature of the form assumed pretty much on the basis of that one phrase above from the spell *alter self* alone.

This DM generally veers toward the spells *alter self et al.* allowing procreation because more plots are down that road, but this player certainly wouldn't leave a campaign if a DM ruled otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

### The game has no rules for procreation

Not officially, at least, which is what are you looking for.
So, we cannot possibly answer this.

Ultimately, you will have to ask your GM for a ruling on your table. Or resort to third-party books, such as the *Book of Erotic Fantasy*, as that is the only book I know of that has [detailed rules about pregnancy](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/108904/21153). It has, for instance, tables to correlate which races may procreate with which, and what **creature types** may procreate with other types. Dragons and outsiders may freely procreate with almost everything, which is how they explained all those half-dragon and half-outsider templates and races. But there are other types that may result in new creatures, such as aberrations resulting in new aberrations, and certain animals resulting in Fey or certain other specific creatures (ie: centaurs).

Comment: According to the SRD: "The subject’s creature type and subtype (if any) change to match the new form."

Comment: @Arthaban You are correct, I remember that wild shape was changed so it clarified that your type didn't change, and I believe that Polymorph had a similar ruling, but it doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

#### There are some rules covering reproduction in D&D, but not in 3rd ed; however there are plenty of official indirect examples in 3rd.

Half-elf, half-orc, half-dragon, half-ogre, half-minotaur, half-dwarf (called a "Mul"), the sorcerer class itself, bloodline levels, the owlbear, the rohch, and so forth; there are many official examples of what happens when one has parents of disparate species, has a *different* sort of ancestor hanging in one's family tree, or falls afoul of meddling wizards or Dragons or Powers.

---

But have you heard of the orc-kobold? Or the pixie-storm giant? (The latter being Gygax's own creation, no less!) Probably not, unless you are a D&D grognard, or have a parent who is one.

---

Thoughts of new racial crossbreeds abounded during the 1st and 2nd edition eras, and the are even rules published about some, usually in Dragon magazine.

Here is a short list of some of the sources:

> "Dragon's Bestiary: Magical Crossbreeds, The"      Jonathan M. Richards    243(75)     D&D2
>
> "What Do You Get When You Cross..."            John S. Olson       44(19)      D&D1
>
> Dragons                "Crossing Dragons With Everything"          Gregory W. Detwiler 170(19)     D&D2
>
> Half-dryad             "Hooves and Green Hair"                 Bennet Marks        109(58)     D&D1
>
> Half-dwarf             "Monstrous Side of the Dark Sun World, The"     Brown & Connors     173(16)     D&D2
>
> Half-giants: DARK SUN          "Monstrous Side of the Dark Sun World, The"     Brown & Connors     173(13)     D&D2
>
> Half-ogre              "Half-Ogre: Smiting Him Hip and Thigh, The"     Gary Gygax      29(12)      D&D1
>
> Half-orcs:             "Half + Half Isn't Always Full"             Paul M. Crabaugh    44(20)      D&D1
>
> Variants               "Half-orcs In a Variety of Styles"          Roger Moore     44(17)      D&D1
>
> Half-satyr             "Hooves and Green Hair"                 Bennet Marks        109(58)     D&D1

---

And this is just a partial list.

Quite a few of these half races were also released in 3rd edition.

What suggestions are given typically use the Punnett square (from genetics and blood types) and also recommend giving children weaker and watered down versions of their parent's powers, probably only some of their powers, not to mention a shorter lifespan and possible sterility.

No super powered offspring to be found in these old suggestions.

While not 3.x material, perhaps this can provide some background and possible guidance, if one has the references handy.

---

Furthermore, even though polymorph affects type, unless the change is permanent, severed parts revert (if I recall correctly) which would include, ah, microscopic parts too, I do believe.

Thus, unless it's a permanent change, it shouldn't affect the reproductive process.

Answer (score 0):

As this is probably up to how the DM wants to run it, I want to give answer related to norse mythology.
https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sleipnir
Odins eight legged horse Sleipnir, was was conceived after Loki had transformed into a female horse, in order to lure away a giants horse. After Loki was impregnated, he was unable to transform back, and had to carry the foal to birth.

Answer (score -2):

The entire body is changed to the creature you polymorphed into. This would include your dna. The only thing that remains is your mind but that is preserved by magical means not physicaly.

I would rule pregnancy as a thing that can be polymorphed. So if you polymorph a pregnant woman into a giraffe the giraffe would no longer be pregnant.

Comment: In that case though: When a bodypart is removed, it reverts to its original form. And of course there's the time limit.

Comment: [Can you provide some back up for this answer?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8696/14878)